# display default text in editedField BlackBerry

Tags: search, blackberry, label

I m trying to add a default Label to searchField when the user put a text "search:" get ereased. I tried this

```
editedField.setLabel("search:")
```

But it doesn't work because when I put a string search don't erase. For exemple If I put "a" it displays searcha. Could you plz help me? thanx a lot.

Comment: if you got your answer, then accept answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need a hint in your `TextField`.

You need to override its `paint` method , You can use this code:

```java
protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
   if (beditfield.getText().length() == 0) 
   {
        graphics.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        graphics.drawText("Search", 0, 0);
   }
   graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
   invalidate();
   super.paint(graphics);
}
```

It checks the textfield length. When it is zero, it draws the hint there.

Comment: I am glad.. It help you !!.. Accept answer if you got your answer

Answer (score 1):

Override [onFocus](http://tinyurl.com/d9lk57e) method and when field is focused, then clear its contents.

To set text field contents use [setText](http://tinyurl.com/cmojvdw) method, instead of `setLabel`

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
private String test="";
final EditField email_edit = new EditField("", "", 30,BasicEditField.FILTER_DEFAULT) {
    String emptyString = "Search";
    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        int oldColor = g.getColor();
        try {
             g.setColor(0x959595);
             test = super.getText();
             if ( test == null || test.length() < 1 ) {
                 g.drawText(emptyString, 0, 0); 
             }
             super.paint(g);
        } finally {
             g.setColor(oldColor);
        }
    }
};
```